# Calling a method of a function constructor from another function in the global scope - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following function constructor

```
function myClass(funcList) {
this.markDone = function() {
console.log("Done");
}
this.execute = function() {
funcList.forEach(function(func){
func.apply(this);
}); 
}
}
```

and I have a couple of functions in the global-scope

```
function func1() {
console.log("func 1");
}

function func2() {
console.log("func 2");
}

var arr = [func1,func2];
```

I can call these functions from the class's context this way

```
var ob = new myClass(arr);
ob.execute(); //this does work
```

How do I invoke markDone from these functions func1 and func2.
If my func1 is

```
function func1() {
console.log("func 1");
markDone();
}
```

and similarly for func 2

This does not work. Shouldn't apply with this take care of the context ?

Comment: you can pass it as callback, but why you want call it inside function instead of after function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close.

1. You need to call `this.markDone();`
2. `this` is set differently inside the `forEach` loop, so you need to set it explicitly or catch it earlier and set it to something else, like `that`

Try this:

```
function func1() {
    console.log("func 1");
    this.markDone();
}
```

And:

```
this.execute = function() {
    var that = this;
    funcList.forEach(function(func){
        func.apply(that);
    }); 
}
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8649hu9s/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way

```
function myClass(funcList) {
    var myClass = this;
    this.markDone = function() {
        console.log("Done");
    }
    this.execute = function() {
        funcList.forEach(function(func){
            func.apply(myClass);
        });
    }
}

function func1() {
    console.log("func 1");
    this.markDone();
}

function func2() {
    console.log("func 2");
}

var arr = [func1,func2];

var ob = new myClass(arr);
ob.execute();
```